net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - when trying to access nginx docker container
I am attempting to containerize my python backend that I am hosting on a GCP compute engine instance. I created two containers, one for the backend server and one for nginx reverse proxy. My docker-compose.yml:
services:
  web:
    image: <me>/fastapiwithnginx:latest
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    restart: unless-stopped
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "1"
        max-size: "100k"
  
  nginx:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - CERTBOT_EMAIL=<my-email>
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/user_conf.d:ro
    #   - /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - web
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100k"
        max-file: "1"

I am able to pull both images in my VM and start containers. I am able to connect to the backend by hitting the ip address at port 8001, but I am unable to connect using my server url. I get a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
My nginx.conf is below:
server {
    listen 443 ssl ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name <my-server-url>; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8001;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/isgs-server.uow-carbon.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/isgs-server.uow-carbon.org/privkey.pem;
}

When I run docker ps -a on my vm, I see the following:
ca318e7b0788   nginx                          "/docker-entrypoint.…"   20 minutes ago   Up 16 seconds             80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   nginx
7cf921b40eab   <me>/fastapiwithnginx:latest   "python app/main.py …"   20 minutes ago   Up 20 minutes             0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp, :::8001->8001/tcp       web


Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

I'm no expert but if you deploy a simple/basic nginx docker container in a GCP compute instance, are you able to access the Welcome basic page from Nginx?
Connection_refused could be a port not opened or miss-configuration in nginx...did you check your GCP VPC Network Firewall configurations?
What does your server URL resolve to?
Food for thought

I'm able to run nginx (and the backend server) outside of the containers and access the server url, so the GPC network firewall configurations seem to be OK. However, when running nginx inside the docker container, the server URL resolves to: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
Just tested deploying a basic nginx docker container (from https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-the-official-nginx-docker-image/), and that also gets ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.. so I think you're right that it must be a miss-configuration in nginx. now I'm wondering which conf file the container is referring to

finally figured it out. seems I was copying my nginx.conf file to the wrong location in docker, in user_conf.d instead of conf.d. also had to rename it to default.conf and now it works ‍♂️

Ah good job !
